# Flutter/dart error:: Textfield controller does not let me delete text without throwing an error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-textformfield

I have a Textfield that allows me to input text, however, when I try to delete a little bit of the text, the program crashes, then my code editor show me the following error page in visual studio code::
[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pr5ng.png)

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: TextFieldScreen(),
  ));
}

class TextFieldScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TextFieldScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<TextFieldScreen> createState() => _TextFieldScreenState();
}

class _TextFieldScreenState extends State<TextFieldScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _emailTextController =
      TextEditingController(text: '');
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: _emailTextController,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to use flutter clean and now I get the following errors (pretty much everything is on red)
[everything goes red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUYcX.jpg)

Comment: Can you try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: flutter clean made everything go red lol.

Comment: after  `flutter clean` get the package `flutter pub get`, rebuilding app should get the package by default. Also does this error happen on web build?

Comment: whats the explanation behind this weird behavior?!?!

Comment: Cant say for sure. On debug mode, sometime things like this happen, try to rebuild the app to overcome this

Answer (score 0):

1. I ran the code and it works flawlessly without so much a warning. So if you are getting error, please upload error log.
2. You didn't upload error logs if there was an error. It is much needed part in question. Uploaded images didn't provide data needed to solve this question.
3. Based on your discussion with @Yeasin Sheikh, you need to follow a beginners tutorial which will solve your most basic issues.